# Is this decomposition of an antisymmetric Tensor always possible?

Tags: tensors

First off: I am not a mathematician and I am not too deeply involved in "pure mathematics". As such my nomenclature may be off. Thus if you think that what I am describing is different from what I am calling it, there might be a good chance I just used the wrong name for it :)

---

I am working with Tensors of e.g. the form $T^{ab}_{ij}$. In this case $T$ is a Tensor with 4 indices $a,b,i,j$.

Starting off from (potentially) non-symmetric tensor elements $t^{ab}_{ij}$, I know I can construct the Tensor $T$ such that it is antisymmetric with respect of index-exchanges between $a$ and $b$ or $i$ and $j$:
$$
T^{ab}_{ij} = - T^{ba}_{ij} = - T^{ab}_{ji} = T^{ba}_{ji}
$$

In order to achieve that, I have to construct the elements of $T$ as
$$
T^{ab}_{ij} = \frac{1}{4} \left( t^{ab}_{ij} - t^{ba}_{ij} - t^{ab}_{ji} + t^{ba}_{ij} \right)
$$
thus: by explicit antisymmetrization of the two index pairs.

However I was wondering if this process is always reversible. Thus given a Tensor $T$ which is antisymmetric with respect to index-exchanges as shown above, is it always possible to perform a deconstruction into the (potentially) non-symmetric tensor $t$?

In cases where $T$ was constructed in the way shown above, it is of course always possible to reverse the operation but suppose you have an arbitrary Tensor $T$ at hand, which happens to have these antisymmetric properties. Is that still possible?

Also is this decomposition of $T$ unique?

And finally: Does this kind of decomposition perhaps have a name that I can use to find out more about it (or use when speaking about this in the future)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This process is *not* reversible : if your indices ranges over $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, the rank-$4$ tensor $t_{ij}^{~~~ab}$ has $n^4$ free components, while the partially antisymmetric one $T_{ij}^{~~~ab}$ has ${n^2(n-1)^2}/4$.

Another way to see this is that if $R^{ab}$ and $M_{ij}$ are two symmetric tensors, then by setting $t_{ij}^{~~~ab} = M_{ij}R^{ab}$, you get $T_{ij}^{~~~ab} = 0$ while $t_{ij}^{~~~ab}$ is not necessarily zero.

Now, if $T_{ij}^{~~~ab}$ has this anti-symmetry property, then :
$$T_{ij}^{~~~ab} = \frac14\left(T_{ij}^{~~~ab}-T_{ij}^{~~~ba}-T_{ji}^{~~~ab} + T_{ji}^{~~~ba}\right)$$

**Conclusion** :

> The map $$t_{ij}^{ab}\longmapsto T_{ij}^{ab}=\frac{1}{4} \left( t^{ab}_{ij} - t^{ba}_{ij} - t^{ab}_{ji} + t^{ba}_{ij} \right)$$
> is onto tensors with this anti-symmetry property, but is never one-to-one.

**Further readings** : to search for true tensor decomposition (one-to-one and onto), I suggest reading the answers [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/45368/can-any-rank-tensor-be-decomposed-into-symmetric-and-anti-symmetric-parts) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/635248/rank-3-tensor-decomposition)

Comment: Did I understand it correctly that given $T$, we could find _some_ $t$ which yields the relation, but the choice of $t$ is not unique?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am stating as a conclusion

Comment: Okay great - just wanted to be sure. Thank you very much!